# Evaluating 3 dB frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier

Given this circuit:

[image]

All the ops are ideal (infinite gain, infinite bandwidth, infinite input resistance and zero output resistance.

I have to calculate the 3 dB frequency of this amplifier which is defined as follows:

$$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_1 - V_2}=A_d$$

Calculating the entire transfer function of this amplifier to its 3 dB frequency is a quite a tedious task and I assume there must be a shortcut method which I'm unfamiliar with, that might make evaluate the 3 dB frequency of this amplifier much more easily.
Can the constants time method be applied here?
How can I use the symmetry in this circuit to evaluate the 3 dB frequency?

Comment: You have two, 1st order lowpass filters, summed up with a 3rd, 1st order lowpass.

Comment: As near as damn it 3978 Hz - no point being ultra accurate cause the resistor tolerances will have a bigger effect than me ignoring the (largely irrelevant) final stage 3 dB point

Comment: This looks like a homework question...otherwise you could just simulate the circuit. We will need you to show us that you have made a **substantial effort** to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work.

Comment: Is the missing capacitor across R11 on purpose?